# Can I use my credit card a day before due date?

Tags: credit-card, balance

Payment due date of my credit card is on March 4th. And I already paid full amount of balance on Feb 26th. If I use my credit card today, which is March 3, should I pay another one by March 4?

(Hi,jamesqf. Even though I already paid, I thought I had to pay it again because it was the amount I used before the payment due date date.)

Comment: Needs more info.  Why do you think you wouldn't be able to use it, unless you've maxed out your credit limit?  And no, you shouldn't have to pay it.  There's a difference (about 2-3 weeks) between the monthly closing date (when everything you've charged the previous month is added up to form the amount due), and the due date, when you have to send them the money.  So if you charge something March 3rd, payment won't be due until April 4th.  (Assuming US credit card laws & practices.)